# Removing programs from startup

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am creating a setup program, that adds a shortcut to startup.  Trying to reinstall the program does not change the disabled status, but if it is removed, it is added again. I want to test reinstalling without uninstalling the program to see if the shortcuts are added correctly.

Is there a way to remove programs from startup, and not just disable them, in Windows 8 and 10?

Where are these items saved in registry?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not just disable them"?  There are a number of different places where programs can be specified to load during startup.  Some of these places can include potential programs in a list and whether or not they run depends on their being selected.  The programs, themselves don't get disabled; they can be loaded later.  Are you referring to removing programs from the various startup lists so they cannot be selected?  If so, what are you anticipating would be different in the system's behavior vs. deselecting them?

Comment: well I am creating a setup program, that add a shortcut to startup, but the problem is, trying to reinstall the program does not change the disabled status. but if it is removed it is added again. I want to test reinstalling without uninstalling the program to see if the shortcuts are added correctly

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the registry, [remove it with Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx):

[image]

Uncheck it first and if you no longer need it, delete the entry completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built tool **System Configuration** to do this.
Search for *msconfig.exe* in Start menu and open it, switch to the **Startup** tab and uncheck those startup programs that you do not need.
[image]
You can disable services from the **Services** tab.

**NOTE:** You have to restart the pc for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can dowload ccleaner http://filehippo.com/download_ccleaner/ this program will show startup programs/ apps and allow you to disable the ones you wish.

Comment: It's best to link to the official Piriform webpage on CCleaner. Linking to another file host makes the answer look like it's trying to evade spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually set each program to not run at start, like unchecked "load at windows startup"

or you can remove manualy on regedit, here :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run